Why can the standard error of the weighted mean be smaller than the standard errors of the individual measurements?
I am combining two independent measurements with their respective standard errors using a weighted mean. The measurements are:

It seems counterintuitive to me that the standard error of the weighted mean (≈0.186) is smaller than the standard error of the first and second measurement (1 and 0.19).
I think it is due to the fact that the second measurement weighs much more than the first, having a lower standard error.
Is it correct, can someone explain why this happens?
Thank you!

The higher n the lower standard error

The short answer, as @LulY pointed out in the comments, is that you now have a larger combined sample size.
Take the standard error of the mean for example:
$$\mathrm{SE} = \frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}$$
Larger $n$, smaller uncertainty.
Intuitively, if the first and second measurement yield a similar value for $x$. Why would the standard error move any other direction than down? After all, you have now twice observed it being in the same vicinity.

Thank you very much! Now it's clear :)
